# Is there a way to implement named let as macro to make it work with Petrofsky let

Tags: scheme

I have Scheme interpreter written in JavaScript. And named let macro expand into `letrec` with lambda expression. But the problem is the Petrofsky let

```lisp
(test.failing "std: Petrofsky let"
      (lambda (t)
        (t.is (let - ((n (- 1))) n) -1)))
```

It expands into:

```lisp
(letrec ((- (lambda (n) n))) (- (- 1)))
```

Is there a way to implement named let as scheme code that will work for Petrofsky let and return `-1`? Or do I need to implement named let as a basic construct in JavaScript?

I will probably implement it in JavaScript, because named let was kind of quick hack added without thinking. But I still want to know if it's possible to do this in Scheme.

Answer (score 3):

One way to implement named `let` without using `letrec` or an equivalent internal `define` is to use a [Y-combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator). Example using a `syntax-rules` transformer:

```lisp
(define-syntax my-named-let
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ name ((id init) ...) body0 body1 ...)
     (((lambda (h)
         ((lambda (x) (h (lambda a (apply (x x) a))))
          (lambda (x) (h (lambda a (apply (x x) a))))))
       (lambda (name) (lambda (id ...) body0 body1 ...))) init ...))))
```

I only saw `define-macro` listed in your documentation, though. Here's a traditional Lisp-style macro version (Tested with Guile and Gauche and also on LIPS):

```lisp
(define-macro (my-named-let name ids-and-inits . body)
  `(((lambda (h)
       ((lambda (x) (h (lambda a (apply (x x) a))))
        (lambda (x) (h (lambda a (apply (x x) a))))))
     (lambda (,name) (lambda ,(map car ids-and-inits) ,@body)))
    ,@(map cadr ids-and-inits)))
```

---

A less esoteric approach is to initially bind all the initializers to temporary variables outside of the `letrec` and then use those variables for the initial call:

```lisp
(define-macro (my-named-let name ids-and-inits . body)
  (let ((temp-ids (map (lambda (id) (gensym)) ids-and-inits)))
    `(let ,(map (lambda (temp-id id-and-init) (list temp-id (cadr id-and-init)))
                temp-ids
                ids-and-inits)
       (letrec ((,name (lambda ,(map car ids-and-inits) ,@body)))
         (,name ,@temp-ids)))))
```

---

With either macro, you should get the expected `-1` from your test case.

Distinguishing a named `let` from a regular `let` in the same macro is left as an exercise for the reader.

---

A version based on the [`syntax-rules` implementation given in R7RS](https://standards.scheme.org/corrected-r7rs/r7rs-Z-H-9.html#TAG:__tex2page_sec_7.3), that uses `letrec` to return the lambda, and then calls that, instead of having the initial call inside the scope of the `letrec`, meaning you don't need the `gensym`'ed temporary variables. This version also supports regular nameless `let` in the same macro:

```lisp
(define-macro (let name-or-bindings body-or-bindings . body)
  (cond
   ((symbol? name-or-bindings)
    `((letrec ((,name-or-bindings (lambda ,(map car body-or-bindings) ,@body)))
        ,name-or-bindings)
      ,@(map cadr body-or-bindings)))
   ((pair? name-or-bindings)
    `((lambda ,(map car name-or-bindings) ,body-or-bindings ,@body)
      ,@(map cadr name-or-bindings)))
   (else (error "invalid syntax for let"))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my case I can't create a macro for named let because the code needs to be written in JavaScript. You can't create a named let unless you change the name of the macro to something else, like in your example. I've created a macro in JavaScript that expands into `let + letrec`. Also it's easier to use code from my answer (even that I didn't created exact macro) were you have single gensym and created a list of arguments. Your last macro will be much simpler.

Comment: @jcubic Huh? Of course a real version would be named `let` and support both regular and named let (just dispatch on if the first argument is a symbol or list). I left that out to focus on the stated issue.

Comment: But you can't create regular let with a macro, `let` needs to be built-in expression written in host language.

Comment: @jcubic You most certainly can use a macro for regular let; I believe that's how most scheme implementations do it. R7RS has an example `syntax-rules` version in the Derived Expression Types section (Combined with named let using a simpler version than mine) . It just turns it into a `lambda` and call of same.

Comment: `let*`, `letrec` and `letrec*` are also usually implemented with macros too, not just `let`.

Comment: @jcubic: `(define-syntax let (syntax-rules () ((_ ((var init) ...) form ...) ((λ (var ...) form ...) init ...))))`

Comment: @ignisvolens Yeah, you're right. I forget that you can create let with lambda.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version which uses neither something like Y nor a bunch of temporary variables, but does use assignment.  The trick is the same one implementations of `letrec` do: bind the function's name to something temporary, then make it be the actual function.

In other words you want

```
(nlet - ((x (- 1))) x)
```

to turn into

```
(let ((- #f) (x (- 1)))
  (set! - (lambda (x) x))
  (- x))
```

This may be incorrect in some way I have not thought of, but I think it's OK.

Here's a `syntax-rules` implementation:

```
(define-syntax nlet
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ name ((var init) ...) form ...)
     (let ((name #f) (var init) ...)
       (set! name (lambda (var ...) form ...))
       (name var ...)))))
```

Here's a traditional-lisp-macro one:

```
(define-macro (nlet name bindings . forms)
  (let ((vars (map car bindings)))
    `(let ((,name #f) ,@bindings)
     (set! ,name (lambda ,vars ,@forms))
     (,name ,@vars))))
```

Both should have better error detection.

Comment: It's probably better to write `lambda` instead of symbol `λ`, because if you execute this, it will throw an error.

Comment: jcubic: changed that.  I forget because I tend to use Racket.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this implementation:

```lisp
(let ((#:args (list (- 1))))
  (letrec ((- (lambda (n) n)))
    (apply - #:args)))
```

Where `#:args` is unique value that can't appear inside user code. In my case, it was a gensym.